# can't navigate to a page when using a class method

Tags: navigation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am working on windows phone 8.1 universal app where I have created a class method and placed it in the NavigationHelper_LoadState method of one of the  pages in my app. My navigation is as follows, I click on a link on my Mainpage and that takes me to the page in question,  where I have placed the class method in LoadState.

The class method checks the authentication state of the user. If the user is not logged in, it is supposed to take him to a separate login page (SHDSignIn from the snippet below).

The problem I am running into is that when I hit that part of the code in my class method, it just steps through the redirect code but doesn't take me to the login page but rather takes me to the  page that was clicked from mainpage.

From the troubleshooting I have done up to this point seems like an issue probably because I am calling the method from NavigationHelper_LoadState and the system doesn't like it?? Can someone please explain and also provide a workaround for this?

Here is my code for the class function:

```cs
public async void SHDAuthState(string errormessage, ProgressBar myprogressbar, TextBlock mytextblock, TextBlock myservernetworkerror)
{
    //Get the values for the userID and password from the settings....
    string shdLoggedInValue = (string)appRoamingSettings.Values["shdLoggedIn"];

    //If not logged in, redirect to the SHD sign in page...
    if (shdLoggedInValue != "Yes")
    {
        this.rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SHDSignIn));
    }

    //Getting the cookie if it has expired..
    else
    {
        //Get the cookie value...
        string myCookieValue = (string)appRoamingSettings.Values["MyCookie"];

        //Get the original cookie obtain time....
        long CookieObtainedTimeValue = (long)appRoamingSettings.Values["CookieObtainedTime"];

        //Convertig date/time back to DateTime object....
        origCookieObtainedTime = DateTime.FromBinary(CookieObtainedTimeValue);

        currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        //Check to see if cookie has expired....
        cookieTimeElasped = currentDateTime - origCookieObtainedTime;
        cookieTimeElapsedMins = cookieTimeElasped.TotalMinutes;

        //  2 days = 2880 mins but we give a margin of 1 minute
        //Get a new cookie if it has expired and save to settings

        if (cookieTimeElapsedMins >= 2879)
        {
            // Start showing the progress bar...      
            mycontrols.progressbarShow(myprogressbar, mytextblock);

            //Get the values for the userID and password from the settings....
           string UserIDValue = (string)appRoamingSettings.Values["UserID"];
           string PasswordValue = (string)appRoamingSettings.Values["Password"];

           //Update the requestData string before sending.....
           requestData = "{" + string.Format(RegisterRequestData, UserIDValue, PasswordValue) + "}";

           string registerResults = await SHDAPI(registerUrl, requestData, errormessage);

           if (registerResults != null)
           {
                // Get the cookie and the time and save it to settings
                var shdCookie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SHDHelper.SHDObject>(registerResults).RegistrationCookie;

                //Save cookie to the app settings
                appRoamingSettings.Values["MyCookie"] = shdCookie;

                //*************************************
                //  build the UI

                //*************************************

               // Stop showing the progress bar...      
               mycontrols.progressbarNoShow(myprogressbar, mytextblock);
           }

           else
           {
               // Stop showing the progress bar...
               mycontrols.progressbarNoShow(myprogressbar, mytextblock);

               //Show the error message...
               myservernetworkerror.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have the rootFrame defined as follows in my class:

```cs
 Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

I am calling the class method from the LoadState method as follows:

```cs
 SHD_helper.SHDAuthState(errorMessage, pgbar, pgText, ServerNetworkError);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Navigate` method is called before the first page is even loaded...

Have you tried to put the method into a new dispatcher action?

```
rootFrame.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    delegate
    {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof (SHDSignIn));
    });
```

But I think you should not check this in the LoadState callback...